# mediaelement.js with GWT

Tags: mediaelement.js

I have a problem for integrate mediaelement in my GWT Integration.

You know in GWT application you have only one HTML page and I need in DialogBox to integrate a video player, video works good but I don't have controls like fullscreen, duration time. That seems that javascript function doesn't work. I use a HTML widget for integrate video tag.

Code :

```
HTML myHTML = new HTML("<body onload='displayPlayer()'>"+
           "<video width='640' height='360' src='vp8.webm' type='video/webm' "+
           "id='player1' "+
        "controls='controls' preload='none'></video>"+                  
        "<span id='player1-mode'></span>"+
        "</body>");

> function displayPlayer()
{
$('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({
    success: function(player, node) {
        $('#' + node.id + '-mode').html('mode: ' + player.pluginType);
    }
});
}
```

I added scripts and CSS in my HTML page

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="displayplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="mediaelement.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="mediaelementplayer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
```

Do you any ideas ?

thanks.